# How to split a value into multiple rows on the newline char in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have have table named `BookInfo` with the following structure:

```
|id  |book_name  |description  |
--------------------------------
|1   |book 1     |harry        |
|    |           |potter       |
|    |           |Part 2       |
|2   |...        |             |
```

How could I split the row (`id=1`) into multiple rows on the newline character (so that `harry \n potter \n Part 2` would be separated into 3 different records: `harry`, `potter` and `Part 2` using a query?

To reiterate, the resultset would look something like this:

```
|id  | description   |
----------------------
|1   |harry          | 
|2   |potter         |
|3   |Part 2         |
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for `regexp_split_to_table()`:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-string.html

```
select regexp_split_to_table('hello world', E'\\s+');

hello
world

(2 rows)
```