# How to get nth line from text column in postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

How to create function

> mline( value text, linenumber integer )

in Postgres 9.1+ which returns line by number from text column.

For example,

```
create table test ( test text );
insert into test values ('Line 1
Line 2
Line 3');
select mline(test,2) from test;
```

should return

> Line 2

Using Postgres 9.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a value into multiple rows on the newline char in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810118/how-to-split-a-value-into-multiple-rows-on-the-newline-char-in-postgresql)

Comment: This returns table. I need to return only specified line, preferably using sql language function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `regexp_split_to_array` and subscript to get specific element:

```
create table test ( test text );
insert into test values ('Line 1
Line 2
Line 3');

SELECT (regexp_split_to_array(test, '\n'))[2] FROM test;
```

Output:

```
Line 2
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=7fe214798234c479b1d9baf5f6703cab)**